# create trigger for "Not allow any other connection into database other than user having DBA priviledge"

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration, database-trigger

I want to create one trigger but i have to create trigger regarding for this

> Not allow any other connection into database other than user having **DBA** priviledge

Comment: Is this an exercise? Otherwise you may prefer `ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit So after using this above query how can we use it into the trigger.

Comment: If you execute `ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION` then you cannot connect to the database anymore unless you have the `RESTRICTED SESSION` privilege - which is included in `DBA` role. There is no need for a trigger.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It is an exercise to create trigger that's why I have to create trigger for this situation.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit How to disable this `ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION` because it is creating some issue in DB.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Fairly obvious: `ALTER SYSTEM DISABLE RESTRICTED SESSION`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement such a restriction is to run

```
ALTER SYSTEM ENABLE RESTRICTED SESSION;
```

which prevents non-DBAs from connecting to the database.

But, as the exercise is to implement a trigger the solution could be this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_LOGON 
    AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

BEGIN
    IF not DBMS_SESSION.IS_ROLE_ENABLED('DBA') THEN
        raise_application_error(-20001, 'You are not permitted to logon');
    end if;
END;
/
```

Actually you can make it even shorter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T_LOGON 
    AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE

BEGIN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'You are not permitted to logon');
END;
/
```

Because as `DBA` you have privilege `ADMINISTER DATABASE TRIGGER` which allows you to logon regardless of errors thrown by a login trigger as a failsafe.

Comment: Two clever solutions. I have injected your comment on the question, because I think the answer should include the correct approach as well as the triggers.

Comment: Typo - error numbers in raise_application_error should be negative.